# Could not find property 'link_to' on object (generated application controller).

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I have a simple `index.html` with an application template that includes:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <nav>
      <ul>
         <li>
           <h1>{{#link_to 'index'}}Bookmarker{{/link_to}}</h1>
         </li>
         <li>
            {{#link_to 'bookmarks'}}Bookmarks{{/link_to}}
         </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

   {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Otherwise my ember code is:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.LSAdapter;

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('bookmarks');
});
```

when running this in the browser I get:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.2.0 ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.e7996c4d ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2 ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.2.0.js:3231
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5374
Uncaught Error: <(subclass of Ember.View):ember258> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'link_to' on object (generated application controller).
```

Comment: looks like you forgot to put '#' or '/' before 'link_to' helper in your code. If you can provide jsfiddle then I can help you further.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot. Use `{{#link-to}}`

Comment: Be carefull `linkTo` is deprecated, use `link-to` when avaliable