# Rendering Ember component (google line chart) with rails backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, charts

Recently I started a project with rails backend and ember js, however I find the documentation on both together is difficult to find or quite ambiguous, however I have parts of my app working perfectly.

Now, I decided to code a google line chart in an ember component. With ember inspector, it tends to throw an error on `localhost:3000/#/chart` currently the error:

```
Uncaught Error: <Sample.ChartView:ember526> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'chart' on object (generated chart controller)
```

So, here's my code for the relevant files:

`assets/javascript/components/chart_component.js`:

```javascript
var data = {
  labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
  datasets : [
    {
      fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      data : [51,10,18,58,65,95,87]
    },
    {
      fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
    }
  ]
};

var data2 = {
  labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
  datasets : [
    {
      fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      data : [51,10,18,58,65,95,87]
    },
    {
      fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
    }
  ]
};

Sample.LineChartComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'canvas',
  attributeBindings: ['width', 'height'],
  width: '480',
  height: '360',
  data: null,
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var ctx = this.get('element').getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(this.get('data'));
  }
});
```

`javascripts/routes/chart_route`:

```javascript
Sample.ChartRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.Object.create({
      modelOne: data,
      modelTwo: data2
   });
  }
});
```

Where I'm calling the chart component.. javascripts/templates/chart.handlebars

```html
<h2>Chart one</h2>

{{chart data= model.modelOne}}

<h2>Chart two</h2>
{{chart data= model.modelTwo}}
```

Comment: Could you post your template where you call the chart component?

Comment: I added the .handlebars file where I'm calling the component, hopefully that will help

Comment: Have you tried googling the error? Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347089/could-not-find-property-link-to-on-object-generated-application-controller), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502806/handlebars-error-could-not-find-property-query-params-although-feature-activa), or [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/233), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22344802/456814)?

Comment: Yes, I have spent hours looking for answers. Hence why I thought it would be better to rephrase my question to bring reduce ambiguity that might've caused the other question not to be answered. I'm quite stuck, and there isn't much documentation on this that's current.

Answer (score 3):

As for the naming convention:

> Components must have a dash in their name. So blog-post is an
>   acceptable name, but post is not. This prevents clashes with current
>   or future HTML element names, and ensures Ember picks up the
>   components automatically.

http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/

As far as I see, you called your component simply "charts", that might be the problem.

Comment: Your filename should match the component name as well. For example you if you call your component chart-compoonent, the filename should be `chart-compoonent.js` (with a dash not underscore) and you would render it by calling `{{chart-component}}`.