# Ember-Rails component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I previously asked a question that wasn't really answered, so I'm trying to ask it in a different way. Let me start by saying, I created an Ember app using a rails backend with the ember-rails gem. I have done a lot of research and I find documentation to be conflicting and outdated.

Part of my application works perfectly, I'm using a story sort of function. However, when I tried to move on and create a component for the application to render a Line chart I soon ran into a lot of errors and confusing outcomes. Quite simply the data will not render at all. The error I get is

```
Uncaught Error: <Sample.ChartView:ember344> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'chart' on object (generated chart controller)
```

- My code is on github.com/fatoblivion/sample
- My previous question: [Rendering Ember component (google line chart) with rails backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408976/rendering-ember-component-google-line-chart-with-rails-backend)

And if you know about any current and up-to-date rails/ember tutorial with components too that would help a lot.

Comment: You're not really supposed to ask the same question if your first one was never answered.